# calling private function inside knockout viewmodel

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have this viewmodel

```
var MyVM = function() {
   var self = this;

   // i wrote private function like this
   function getNames() {
      //some logic
   }

   //i want to call function inside this code
   $("body").on("onTrigger", (evt, msg) => {
      getNames();
   });

}
```

but it doesnt call the function `getNames()`. How to call private function?

Comment: That should work as long as the event listener attached to `body` is valid (`onTrigger` isn't valid). Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/s095edh1/ Can you create a minimal snippet or fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

try to make changes in your code like this,

```
var names = {
getNames : function(){
//some logic 
}}
```

then call the function this way:

```
names.getNames();
```

or create an object of MyVM and call like this:

```
MyVM names = new MyVM();
names.getNames();
```